setting a datetime into global application item
Oracle APEX 24.1

I have 3 application items.


I have this procedure
  procedure set_globals is    
  begin 

  apex_debug.message(p_message => 'Setting system globals'); 
  apex_util.set_session_state('G_DATE', sysdate); 
  ....
  ....
  apex_debug.message(p_message => 'System globals set');    

  exception when others then 
  apex_debug.error(p_message => 'Error setting global variables: ' || sqlerrm); 

  end set_globals;


I call this procedure on my Application Security Attributes page's Database Initialization PL/SQL Code section.

I have a page to see what these variables hold



my question:
I couldn't get sysdate assigned to G_DATE as dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss
Can someone tell me what am I missing here?

Looks like a rounding issue. In apex, items (both application and page) do not have a datatype under the hood. They're all strings. So... try TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') instead.

apex_util.set_session_state('G_DATE', to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
worked!
thank you Koen!
